# Why can't jasmine find my source code with rake jamine:ci?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, rake, jasmine2.0

I can `rake jasmine` to run the server and then visit

http://localhost:8888/SpecRunner.html

and I get

[image]

but when I do `rake jasmine:ci` `0 specs` are found.  I moved `PlayerSpec.js` to `spec/javascripts/` and they were found but now they all fail with errors such as

```
Player should be able to play a Song

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Player in http://localhost:45147/__spec__/PlayerSpec.js (line 6)
...
```

It seems that the `src/Player.js` file isn't being used as that is where Player is defined, i.e.

```
function Player() {
}
Player.prototype.play = function(song) {
...
```

Where should I be putting the source file `Player.js` as `src` isn't working ?
I've tried putting the `Player.js` file in `spec/` and `spec/javascripts/` but it didn't help, same error.

I tried inserting the Player function at the top of the spec file but that didn't help, same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by the `spec/javascripts/support/jasmine.yml` file

I was able to get `rake jasmine:ci` to use the same source and spec files as used by `rake jasmine` by updating the `jasmine.yml` file, specifically

```
src_files:
  - src/Player.js
  - src/Song.js
```

and

```
# spec_dir: Example spec/javascripts
#
spec_dir: spec
```

This solved most of my issues.  2 specs are still failing as they aren't finding Song which exists in `src` and is included as shown but that is a separate issue I am looking into.